# Smooth function over a manifold into an algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds, tensor-products

Let $M$ be a manifold and $A$ a $*$-algebra. Does is hold that 
$$C^{\infty}(M,A) \cong C^{\infty}(M) \otimes A$$
where the RHS means that you take smooth functions which map into $A$. If this holds, do you have a proof?

Comment: If $A$ is finite dimensional, this is trivial (pick a basis for $A$). If not, then you need to be more specific on the conditions you agree to on $A$ (topology, etc.).

Comment: Since $C^\infty(M)$ is a nuclear Frechet space you can choose more or less any of the usual tensor topologies (like the projective $\pi$ or the injective $\varepsilon$) and you get $C^\infty(M,A)\cong C^\infty(M) \tilde{\otimes} A$ (the completed tensor product) for all Banach (or Frechet) spaces $A$.